# Ensuring sequential file access with Windows Runtime async file API?

Tags: .net, multithreading, file-io, windows-runtime, async-await

When writing a file using the Windows Runtime, all methods are asynchronous. Is it possible to ensure that my file access and writes are done sequentially in this scenario?

For example, if I have a logging class that may be called from multiple other asynchronous and possibly parallel code, how might I ensure the logger actually writes to a file synchronously?

Due to using async/await, I can't just put a lock around the file access like:

```
lock (locker)
{
    var storageFile = await GetStorageFileAsync();
    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(storageFile, text);
}
```

I was wondering if a BufferBlock from the Dataflow TPL would work in this scenario to serialize the writing, but I'm unsure of exactly how to set that up. I think it would look like:

```
static readonly BufferBlock<string> LogBuffer = new BufferBlock<string>();

public async static Task LogAsync(string message)
{
    LogBuffer.Post(message);

    string messageToWrite;
    while (LogBuffer.TryReceive(out messageToWrite))
    {
        var storageFile = await GetStorageFileAsync();
        await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(storageFile, messageToWrite);
    }
}
```

It's likely that I'm mixing up asynchronous and multi-threaded programming, but I thought when using Tasks that you can't be sure which thread you code will be called on. In this case, I want to ensure only one thread can access the file at a time. Am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is *synchronized* asynchronous code. Async code by default is sequential (if you `await` one operation, then the method will not continue until that operation is completed); you want it to be synchronized. Not "synchronous", either; you still want it to be asynchronous.

You can just use `SemaphoreSlim` as an `async`-compatible `lock` to synchronize asynchronous code:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

...

await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
try
{
  var storageFile = await GetStorageFileAsync();
  await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(storageFile, text);
}
finally
{
  _semaphore.Release();
}
```

That said, you may prefer an `ActionBlock` if you want the rest of the code to continue immediately after *queueing* the write instead of (asynchronously) waiting for the write to complete.

Comment: Queuing the write is exactly what I want. I didn't know about SemaphoreSlim and will look into it. Thanks for explaining this.